# Minimum value of php memory_limit

Tags: php, memory, memory-limit

I'm trying to grasp the basics of PHP's memory allocation and it seems that I'm missing some basics.
Let's say we have the following code:

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit','10000');

$a = '';
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
    $a .= '1';
}
```

The execution of this yields the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 153801 bytes) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7
```

So that means that the ini_set of memory was not taken into account for this value (with a considerably bigger one it is OK). Is there a hard minimun of 0.25MB (262144 bytes) for this operation?

Also, supposedly we have just an empty script, doing nothing and we invoke

```
echo memory_get_usage(true);
```

This is going to output 786432 bytes.

So I'm confused. An empty script is utilizing 0.75M of memory. If I limit the allowed memory to 262144 via an ini_set command, how the script can be executed (it executes OK still..)

Comment: Anyone on this? I'm curious too as PHP memory management has something weird in it.